# Rocket raid 2320 drivers for Debian Wheezy

Tags: linux, debian, raid, debian-wheezy

I want to use this board on my server when I upgrade it to Debian Wheezy (and I would like for it to continue to work on Debian Jessie when that is released).

So far the "open source" drivers at High point's website seems a bit old and I would not risk installing those until I know of there are better options available.
I am not interested in the boards raid functionallity at all only JBOD. What are my options to get this board working "out of the box" without any extra installs?

Answer (score 0):

Found this question googling for software for my Rocket Raid product. Figured I'd answer for the next Goo-gler.

I used the RR3510 for a couple years (10?) without drivers. I configured it at the BIOS when the computer was starting up. I'm using mine as a RAID6.

Installing debian today after running ubuntu 10.04 LTS server for the past few years: if there are "drivers", the OS installer for debian (and ubuntu) handles the RocketRaid, as it was immediately in the partitioning tools. Note: OSs will lose track of device allocation, so my raid is `/dev/sda` sometimes and `/dev/sdb` others; since I have one 4T partition, it wasn't hard to spot. I installed their WebGUI on Ubuntu years ago and forgot I had it. At some point, the RAID alarm sounded and bios said a drive was failing, so I did a final backup, bought 4 new drives, and copied the backup to new drives.

I fully expect if you put it into JBOD via the BIOS, it will make the board transparent to the OS and all the drives will show up as expected -- **but who knows what `/dev` will do!** Probably best if the drives are all different sizes/brands.

I'm looking for the software now is to see about tuning caching since I have the optional BBU...

**Edit:** downloaded the items in the "Linux" row [from here for my 3510](http://www.highpoint-tech.cn/usa/bios_rr3520.htm) in the "RAID Management Utility" section and unzipped WebGUI. I'm running Debian 7.3 x86_64; apt-get alien and ran:
`# alien -d --scripts hptsvr-https-1.4-6.x86_64.rpm`
then installed with 
`# dpkg -i`

It installs a xen? server on port 7402. [This is the help page for the WebGUI](http://www.highpoint-tech.com/help/). I remember this interface; I'll study up on the caching and options to understand the [recommendations given in this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/511443/raid-battery-and-ups).

Snapshot of the GUI is interesting in that it came up JBOD even though I'm RAID6 - so these controls are what to change TO without respect of what IS:
[image: snapshot of gui]

Comment: For your information: If you refer to your disks by UUID (ls -la /dev/disk/by-uuid/ you avoid the issue with sda becomming sdb etc.

Comment: I know ... I use uuid in fstab, but otherwise generally don't unless I take notes & write the last 6#s on the drive itself with a sharpie. :P